# How to skip paypal thank you page?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

In paypal, is it possible to skip the "Thanks for your order page" and come directly back to our store? Here i have attached the screenshot of the page which is coming after "Pay Now" page and this is the page i want to skip and i need to directly go to my website from where the process is initiated.[image]

Comment: u dont want user to have this "thanks for your order" page?? or you want user to be redirected to the page whr the process initiated???

Comment: Ya i want the user to be redirected to the page where the process initiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these settings at your paypal account --

1. click at edit profile tab in your paypal acc.
2. click “website payment preferences” under “selling
   preferences”
3. click “on” for `auto-return`.
4. enter a return URL.
5. Save.

Let me know if u face any prob while configuring.

**NEW EDIT**

You can also pass like this --

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="return" value="URLspecificToThisTransaction">
```

Comment: @Udhay and you configured the settings as well??

Comment: What settings i have to configure?

Comment: @Udhay above mentined settings at your account

Comment: Hi Swapnesh, thanks for you answer. But the problem is my website is a online store where multiple users can have their own seller details to sell their item through my website. So i cant change that option in my sellers account.

Comment: @Udhay actually u only need to set a URL then other URL will overwrite the existing ones

Comment: Do i need to pass it as a paypal variable?